# Why is my Windows Application Packaging Project stripping all my native libraries from the published package?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

My application uses some native libraries from nuget packages, like [ManagedWimLib](https://github.com/ied206/ManagedWimLib).

This nuget package automatically copies the native libraries on build, targeting a number of platforms (Win, Linux, Mac...). The files are placed inside the **bin** folder of the application, under subfolders like

- `runtimes/[platform]/native`
- `runtimes/[platform]/lib`

So, when debugging the application, if you go to the bin folder of the application, the **runtimes folder** contains the right file structure with all their dlls.

BUT:

**When I publish the packaging project**, inside its **bin\x64\Release\Deployer.Gui\runtimes** folder, all the folders and libraries are missing. There's no .dll file in there. It looks like the packaging project is ignoring the native libraries completely.

What can I do to make it include them?